# Call to undefined method PDOStatement::numColumns()

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo

I can't run the method [`numColumns()`](http://php.net/manual/de/sqlite3result.numcolumns.php) on my `$result`.

My code:

```
try {
    $db = new PDO('sqlite:temps.sqlite',null,null,array(
      PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
    ));

} catch (PDOException $e) {

    print 'Exception : ' . $e->getMessage();
}

$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM data LIMIT 30");

$fields = $result->numColumns();
```

The error is the following one:

```
Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method PDOStatement::numColumns() in /*/export.php:7 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /*/export.php on line 7
```

(line 7 is the last one)

Why does it not work?

Comment: Because you use PDO and __not__ SQLite3?

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to execute functions from different APIs. You call for `PDO`, but trying to execute `numColumns` from `SQLite3Result`.

As the [docs state](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php#refsect1-pdo.query-returnvalues), `PDO::query()` returns a `PDOStatement` object and your error also points you to that:

> Call to undefined method **PDOStatement**::numColumns()

You need to execute [`columnCount`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.columncount.php) instead:

```
$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM data LIMIT 30");

$fields = $result->columnCount();
```

Or if you wish to work with `SQLite3`, initialize an `SQLite3` connection:

```
$db = new SQLite3('mysqlitedb.db');
$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM data LIMIT 30");
$fields = $result->numColumns();
```